# AX2009 - How do I create a Sales Order of "Journal" type if my default Sales Type is "Sales order"?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, aif

AX2009. We have our AR parameters for AIF default Order Type to "Sales Order". However, there are instances where orders must come in as "Journal" type. Changing the SalesType in the xml to "Journal" does not seem to work. Is there a way to do accomplish this, maybe at the Endpoint setup? Thanks.

Comment: not sure this is a programming question?

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

This parameter is called in the Class AxdSalesOrder in the method prepareSalesOrder as follows:

```
_axSalesTable.parmSalesType(this.SalesType());
```

This sets the sales type to the sales type held in your AR parameters. in this method, you can add code to change the parmSalesType to be `SalesType::Journal`based on whatever criteria you specify.